# &zwnj; changed to &nbsp; by javascript or DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, escaping

I am creating web based application where I let user prepare HTML email. Part of the html email is also PREHADER. To display preheader nice we use [The Preview Text Hack You May Want to Use in Every Email](https://%20https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-little-known-preview-text-hack-you-may-want-to-use-in-every-email) But strangely `&zwnj;` is somehow changed to `&nbsp;`

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/dmeqc34b/1/) that shows that it happens

[image]

Could someone explain why inspector shows correct string but string exported from DOM is different? Could you suggest how to solve this?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/mNqqan4.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character represented by `&zwnj;` is not replaced by `&nbsp;`. What you see happening is that this character is not rendered as an HTML entity, but really with the character itself (which is a zero-width space, so not visible). The `&nbsp;` you see is just the character that *follows* that `&zwnj;`.

It becomes easier to spot when you reduce the HTML and text to a bare minimum:

```js
var html = document.querySelector("div").innerHTML;
console.log("full HTML content:", html);
console.log("length:", html.length); // 8
console.log("is first char an ampersand?:", html[0] === "&");
console.log("is last char a semi-colon?:", html[7] === ";");
console.log("character code of first character:", html.charCodeAt(0));
console.log("character code of last character:", html.charCodeAt(7));

var text = document.querySelector("div").textContent;
console.log("as plain text, length is:", text.length); // 3

console.log("encoded back:", html.replace(/\u200c/g, "&zwnj;"));
```

```html
<div>&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;</div>
```

Take note of the length that is reported: 8 (not 6 for just `&nbsp;`), and the character codes that precede and follow `&nbsp;`. I hope this explains it.

Comment: is there any way I can get `&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;` using javascript? as a text and use it exactly as it is? in HTML?

Comment: also why is  `&nbsp;‌` replaced by ``&amp;nbsp;‌` ? when displaying innerHTML in console

Comment: I added one line to the script that displays the `&zwnj;` again, but you'll need to do that for all special entities. JavaScript will only encode a few characters as HTML entities, including `&nbsp;`, but for most you will have to implement the encoding yourself.

Comment: As to your second comment, I suppose you refer to the output you get in JS fiddle: that is  specific to how the "console" of JS fiddle works. If you check your **browser's** console, you'll not see that kind of output.

Comment: in my solution I was using .replace() but I thought it was wrong so I posted this question hopping the I would get proper solution. I thought that replace was just workaround.